# Custom Android View displaying differently in Linear and Relative Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I've created a custom view (ArrowContainer) to wrap around other elements giving them an arrow shaped background. However, my view displays differently when contained in a Relative Layout to how it displays when contained in a Linear Layout.

Here is the problem, the top ArrowContainer is contained in a LinearLayout and behaves correctly, the bottom ArrowContainer is contained in a RelativeLayout and behaves incorrectly.

[image: An image showing the problem]

Has anyone seen something like this before? The debug code I have inserted in ArrowContainer.java suggests that the problem arises from RelativeLayout measuring the view twice, but I'm not sure why this causes a problem...

Below is the code:

ArrowContainer.java

```
package com.example.arrowcontainertest;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ArrowContainer extends ViewGroup {

    private static final int ARROW_LEFT = 0;
    private static final int ARROW_RIGHT = 1;
    private static final int ARROW_BOTH = 2;

    private static final int DEFAULT_COLOUR = 0xFFFF0000;

    private static final int HORIZONTAL_PADDING = 150;

    private Path path;
    private Paint paint;
    private int arrowSide = ARROW_RIGHT;
    private int colour = DEFAULT_COLOUR;
    private int downColour;
    private Paint downPaint;
    private Boolean isButton = false;

    private View child;

    public ArrowContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }


    public ArrowContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ArrowContainer, 0, 0);

        try {
            arrowSide = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ArrowContainer_arrowSide, ARROW_RIGHT);
            colour = a.getColor(R.styleable.ArrowContainer_colour, DEFAULT_COLOUR);
            isButton = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ArrowContainer_isButton, false);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

        init();
    }

    public ArrowContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ArrowContainer, 0, 0);

        try {
            arrowSide = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ArrowContainer_arrowSide, ARROW_RIGHT);
            colour = a.getColor(R.styleable.ArrowContainer_colour, DEFAULT_COLOUR);
            isButton = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ArrowContainer_isButton, false);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(colour);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        if (isButton) {
            setFocusable(true);
            setClickable(true);

            downColour = 0xFF00FF00;
            downPaint = new Paint();
            downPaint.setColor(downColour);
            downPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        // Must have exactly 1 child
        assert getChildCount()==1;
        if (getChildCount() == 1) {
            child = getChildAt(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // Debug
        Log.e("DEBUG", "Type:" + getParent().getClass());
        Log.e("DEBUG", "Width Mode: " + MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec));
        Log.e("DEBUG", "Height Mode: " + MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec));
        Log.e("DEBUG", "Width Size: " + MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec));
        Log.e("DEBUG", "Height Size: " + MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));   


        // Restrict the childs width to at most this components size minus a fixed value (HORIZONTAL_PADDING*numArrows)
        int numArrows=0;
        switch (arrowSide) {
            case ARROW_RIGHT:
                numArrows = 1;
                break;
            case ARROW_LEFT:
                numArrows = 1;
                break;
            case ARROW_BOTH:
                numArrows = 2;
                break;
        }
        int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)-HORIZONTAL_PADDING*numArrows, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        child.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        int width = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        setMeasuredDimension(width + (int) (numArrows*height/2f), height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();
        int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        switch (arrowSide) {
            case ARROW_RIGHT:
                // Hug left
                child.layout(0, height/2 - childHeight/2, width - height/2, height/2 + childHeight/2);
                break;
            case ARROW_LEFT:
                // Hug right
                child.layout(height/2, height/2 - childHeight/2, width, height/2 + childHeight/2);
                break;
            case ARROW_BOTH:
                // Center
                child.layout(width/2 - childWidth/2, height/2 - childHeight/2, width/2 + childWidth/2, height/2 + childHeight/2);
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        path = new Path();
        switch (arrowSide) {
            case ARROW_RIGHT:
                path.lineTo(0, h);
                path.lineTo(w-h/2f, h);
                path.lineTo(w, h/2f);
                path.lineTo(w-h/2f, 0);
                break;
            case ARROW_LEFT:
                path.moveTo(h/2f, 0);
                path.lineTo(0, h/2f);
                path.lineTo(h/2f, h);
                path.lineTo(w, h);
                path.lineTo(w, 0);  
                break;
            case ARROW_BOTH:
                path.moveTo(h/2f, 0);
                path.lineTo(0, h/2f);
                path.lineTo(h/2f, h);
                path.lineTo(w-h/2f, h);
                path.lineTo(w, h/2f);
                path.lineTo(w-h/2f, 0);
                break;
        }
        path.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        invalidate();
        if (isPressed()) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, downPaint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.arrowcontainertest">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.example.arrowcontainertest.ArrowContainer
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:arrowSide="right">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play"
            android:textSize="50sp"/>
    </com.example.arrowcontainertest.ArrowContainer>   

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.example.arrowcontainertest.ArrowContainer
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:arrowSide="right">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play"
            android:textSize="50sp"/>
    </com.example.arrowcontainertest.ArrowContainer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.arrowcontainertest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

Comment: It is good that you have found solution, but i want to say, that you should use actual values of view dimensions supplied by parent view instead of measured values. I mean `l`, `t`, `r` and `b` in `onLayout`. If you View measured itself, let's say 100x100, but you want to expand it to fill width of parent, you will get nothing if you use measured values instead of those supplied by parent.

Comment: Thanks, will do that in future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update:

I've been unable to solve this problem and this component has been causing problems in other situations. As such I decided to rewrite the component to use a little custom functionality as possible.

My solution has been to create a custom LinearLayout which contains a nested LinearLayout. The outer layout is responsible for drawing the background, and applies sufficient padding to allow space to draw the arrows. All children get passed to the inner layout. This solution isn't perfect as there is often excess padding and so wasted space, but it is sufficient for my purposes.

Code is here:

```
package com.example.arrowcontainertest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class NewArrowContainer extends LinearLayout {

    private static final int ARROW_LEFT = 0;
    private static final int ARROW_RIGHT = 1;
    private static final int ARROW_BOTH = 2;
    private static final int DEFAULT_COLOUR = 0xFFFF0000;
    private static final int ARROW_MAX_WIDTH = 150;

    private LinearLayout childLayout;

    private Path path;
    private Paint paint;
    private int arrowSide = ARROW_RIGHT;
    private int colour = DEFAULT_COLOUR;
    private int downColour;
    private Paint downPaint;
    private Boolean isButton = false;

    public NewArrowContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public NewArrowContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ArrowContainer, 0, 0);

        try {
            arrowSide = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ArrowContainer_arrowSide, ARROW_RIGHT);
            colour = a.getColor(R.styleable.ArrowContainer_colour, DEFAULT_COLOUR);
            isButton = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ArrowContainer_isButton, false);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

        init();
    }

    public NewArrowContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ArrowContainer, 0, 0);

        try {
            arrowSide = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ArrowContainer_arrowSide, ARROW_RIGHT);
            colour = a.getColor(R.styleable.ArrowContainer_colour, DEFAULT_COLOUR);
            isButton = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ArrowContainer_isButton, false);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(colour);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        if (isButton) {
            setFocusable(true);
            setClickable(true);

            downColour = 0xFF00FF00;
            downPaint = new Paint();
            downPaint.setColor(downColour);
            downPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        }

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.arrow_container, this);
        childLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.child);

        // Pass properties to childLayout
        childLayout.setPadding(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop(), getPaddingRight(), getPaddingBottom());
        childLayout.setOrientation(getOrientation());

        // Give the padding sufficient for arrows
        switch (arrowSide) {
            case ARROW_RIGHT:
                setPadding(0, 0, ARROW_MAX_WIDTH, 0);
                break;
            case ARROW_LEFT:
                setPadding(ARROW_MAX_WIDTH, 0, 0, 0);
                break;
            case ARROW_BOTH:
                setPadding(ARROW_MAX_WIDTH, 0, ARROW_MAX_WIDTH, 0);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void setColour(int colour) {
        paint.setColor(colour);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        // Pass all children to the childLayout
        while (getChildCount() > 1) {
            View v = getChildAt(1);
            removeViewAt(1);
            childLayout.addView(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        path = new Path();
        switch (arrowSide) {
            case ARROW_RIGHT:
                path.lineTo(0, h);
                path.lineTo(w-ARROW_MAX_WIDTH, h);
                path.lineTo(w-ARROW_MAX_WIDTH+h/2f, h/2f);
                path.lineTo(w-ARROW_MAX_WIDTH, 0);
                break;
            case ARROW_LEFT:
                path.moveTo(ARROW_MAX_WIDTH-h/2f, h/2f);
                path.lineTo(ARROW_MAX_WIDTH, h);
                path.lineTo(w, h);
                path.lineTo(w, 0);
                path.lineTo(ARROW_MAX_WIDTH, 0);    
                break;
            case ARROW_BOTH:
                path.moveTo(ARROW_MAX_WIDTH-h/2f, h/2f);
                path.lineTo(ARROW_MAX_WIDTH, h);
                path.lineTo(w-ARROW_MAX_WIDTH, h);
                path.lineTo(w-ARROW_MAX_WIDTH+h/2f, h/2f);
                path.lineTo(w-ARROW_MAX_WIDTH, 0);
                path.lineTo(ARROW_MAX_WIDTH, 0);
                break;
        }
        path.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        invalidate();
        if (isPressed()) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, downPaint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)-HORIZONTAL_PADDING*numArrows, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
```

I am concerned about this line, why you don't check if width, supplied to makeMeasureSpec, isn't negative? This method doesn't perform range check, so it your responsibility. Negative width = invalid measureSpec = undefined behavior.

Also, when i have implemented some custom layouts, i've used `super.onMeasure` to determine maximum available dimensions and then used them via `getMeasuredWidth()`, `getMeasuredHeight()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I hadn't thought to check that, I will do in future! It doesn't seem to be a problem in this case however, as in the problematic case it is positive.